# My Blender File Won't Render!

Tags: rendering

I've got a  file and it fails to render, I'm not sure why.

When I hit the render button a grey pixelated screen comes up and it doesn't seem to process. I've tried playing around with the settings, but I get nothing. When I hit Open GL render then it looks like the render version of the image, but  it doesn't include the background color scheme!

Comment: As long as your question is that general, I doubt that anyone will want to guess the dozens of possible reasons why you don't produce an image. Please be more specific. Do you get a black screen? does Blender crash? Does anything happen when you press F12? Have you tried rendering from the menu instead of the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: And, maybe, add a link to your .blend for us to see what happen?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding.. When you press OpenGL render it looks like the actual render, not an opengl render?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. Please edit the question with more specific details and attach screenshots and or a blend-file.

Comment: OpenGl Render doesn't render the World Color. It renders the theme color. Hit Numpad 0 to check where the camera points. Put a new object (shift a) right in front of the camera and testrender, then provide more detail. We'll work it out.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5286/1259  Sounds like your problem. Short answer: Check for any stray video strips in the VSE.