# Blender is rendering an older version my project

Tags: rendering

Blender is rendering an older version of my project, not the most recent one. I have made it using the Blender Render but it does not want to render in cycles either. A black and grey screen is rendered as if everything is transparent. Checked general camera, lighting and compute devises in case I messed something up but I can't find anything. All my textures and objects look normal, does anybody know what is wrong or what to check?

Ok added link:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/ah0brd38psfyb7i/Bathroom%20test%20upload.blend

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend (e.g. to [pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/)) and put the link here? As it is now this could be caused by many things and we can't do much more than speculate.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because you have some sequencer strips in the [VSE](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Usage).

The [*Compositor* and *Sequence*  settings](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render#Post_Processing) are enabled by default, so if there is any data in the compositor or the sequencer blender will render from that instead of the scene.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render#Post_Processing):

> If
>   you are using the [Compositor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes) or [Sequencer](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer), you can tell Blender to
>   process those effects instead of directly rendering the scene.

Disable *Sequence* in *Render Settings > Post processing* or remove the sequencer strips and it will render the scene instead:

version 2.8x

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Had exactly the same problem just a couple of hours ago (mind link with the OP? ;) ) and had been searching my a** off since...