# Blender Cycles Render shows old image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a file that I have made a significant amount of changes to. When I try to render it now, it shows an old image from a few weeks ago that I rendered and no file is saved. Does this sound familiar at all? I'm kind of going crazy.

I'm not sure if there are any settings I need to show, but if there are, I would be glad to post them. I'm using Version 2.70.

Comment: Do you have any strips in the VSE? If not, then the easiest way to find out what's going on is to poke around the file.. Is it possible you could upload it?

Comment: I do have a strip in the VSE, but I've never even touched the VSE before. I will try uploading the file real quick.

Comment: See [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5285/599). If that doesn't fix it, [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) is a convenient blender-specific hosting service :)

Comment: That was crazy easy, thanks. I just deleted the strip from the VSE and it worked!