# The animation in my timeline is not displayed when I hit the Animation button

Tags: animation

I previously animated a short animation. I wanted to redo the animation. So I redid the animation and it can be seen when you scrub through the frames in the time frame but when you hit the animation button it replays the old animation. Can can I force blender to use the new keyframes?

Comment: do you have any old strips on the VSE? Can you see your new animation if you unccheck the box on Scene->PostProcessing->Sequencer?

Comment: That worked! I do not know understand what was happening though. Do you care to explain with an answer so you can get credit for this solution?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5285/599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite common to render an animation, load it in the Video Sequence Editor, and forget that it was there. If you make changes to your 3D scene and render, you'd be looking at your old scene, not the newly altered one. The video strips on the VSE override your 3D scene unless you unclick the sequencer checkbox.

[image]

[image]