# Why is my camera pan not rendering

Tags: rendering, camera

I am a beginner in blender and I made a quick animation of an object that does not move and the camera pans around it. When I press the play button in the camera view, it pans around fine. But when I render it, all the frames are the same. Every object is there and all but the camera does not pan. Please help as soon as you can.

http://pasteall.org/blend/33664

Comment: You're rendering out an animation, correct?

Comment: It works just fine for me.

Comment: yes i am rendering an animation with all of the frames rendering the same

Comment: It does not work here either... Renderer Pro + eGPU. Works with Eevvee and eGPU

Comment: This question does not make sense anymore once the link to the file is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck the Sequencer box in the Post Processing panel.

[image]

Comment: I think that did it, but could you explain what that does please?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5286/1853

Answer (score 0):

The `Render` button or <kbd>F12</kbd> will render the current frame, i.e. the frame you're at in the timeline. The image will not be automatically saved to disk. You have to do that manually.
The `Animation` button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> will render the animation and save it to disk in the directory specified under `Output`. The number of frames rendered is controlled by `Start Frame`, `End Frame` and `Frame Step`.
[image]

Comment: I have done all of that but still, all of the 120 frames I have render the same

Comment: @Lando I see. I interpreted "it just renders one frame" as exactly that, and not as several identical frames. As you say it works in the 3D view, I take it you have keyframed the animation properly. I think you should upload your .blend file to http://pasteall.org/blend and edit your question to include the link to it.

Comment: OK I added the link to the page.