# Image not found may be unpacked or not saved after animation problem

Tags: rendering

I broke something. I rendered an animation out. Didnt like the final output.

Made Adjustments and tried to just render the single frame to check out the output and see if I was happy. Kept showing old render views not the new one(I have overwrite checked) I got impatient deleted the old camera, inserted a new one, moved all the rendered files out of the temp folder, then tried to re- render in the new view, no. Then  now I get blank alpha channel upon trying to view render. The render view works in 3d view, but not upon actually rendering image. I went into the dope sheet and deleted all key frames, so I got the animation part cleared, but dunno why I cant see the render any more
[image]

Comment: It is very likely that you have some sort of modifier or other setting that looks a certain way in the viewport, but the settings are different for the render.  I had a similar problem using a SubSerf modifier.  This may not be your problem, but it is something to look into.

Comment: More screenshots of the scene (used modifiers, scene debug, etc) and / or blend file would be quite helpful. It's not clear enough wtat's the problem or the error.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering

Comment: do you have any strips on the VSE? did you uncheck sequencer on the Post processing section?