# Render Problems with VSE

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, video-sequence-editor

I have been trying to render an animated movie I made and before the rendering was doing what it was supposed to be doing: doing a sequence render where it renders everything I did in the VSe and the 3D default view...

But that doesn't seem to be the case any more, I changed the render samples to 40 and I changed the resolution to 40%, now instead of doing a "Sequence Render" it's doing just a render... I want everything rendered out that I put into the VSE not just the Scene.

Comment: It *should* [default to the VSE if there is anything there](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5285/599). Is it possible you could upload a .blend?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, under your *Render Properties* in the *Post Processing* panel you have **Compositing** and **Sequencer** checked.

Also make sure to hit **Animation** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> for your Rendering, not just **Render** <kbd>F12</kbd>.