# My lowest panel is changing from the editor window to the rendered view

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

**ORIGINAL**:

Have made several videos successfully but suddenly my [render] button does nothing but change my lowest panel from the editor to the result view

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSN98.png

changes to

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUEHN.png

I also noticed it does pop up "Sequence Render" for a very fast moment in place of the blender version above preview. I've never had this happen before and when I try to find previous mentions for help I get bogged down in threads about 3d rendering. I've not changed my settings except to increase the Sequence/Clip Editor Cache. I've checked my properties to make sure those are the same as before. Dimensions, fps, start and end frames, output folder is correct, encoding is the h264 preset, ac3 audio.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33558/how-does-blender-decide-in-which-window-it-shows-the-render/33560#33560

Comment: While interesting and I'm glad to know better now what this means it does not change anything other than a visual function. Still tho, thank you. I hated that it kept stealing that section of my  work.

Comment: Maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38098/2843

Comment: @Andale instead of adding to the question and altering the title, please write an answer to your own question, then mark that as accepted. please read the followingn links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm used to reddit and a few others that use flair or edited titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I had a combination of two issues.

Firstly, I have about 3 minutes of blank video so rather than showing black the preview window shows the gray background that is throughout Blender. This made me assume it wasn't working because it was not black, but really it was just transparent.

Secondly, I set it again, then left to make dinner. Turns out it takes a long time to start up (I guess). I've watching it right now and it is creating the video at about 2/3 speed of original footage in the preview. This is largest video in blender by about double in time and also my first 1080 rather than 720. I guess I was just too impatient.

The important thing is I learned some stuff today. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the [alternative preview](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43779/2843) range enabled and your Properties Frame Range matches your timeline ones, it looks like your Sequencer isn't considered any more... Make sure, the *Sequencer* checkbox in *Post Processing* Panel from your *Render* Properties Tab is [selected](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47323/2843):

[image: Sequencer checkbox in Post Processing Panel]
Though as you mention this quick popup that might already be the case.

Comment: You could as well try to use the [OpenGL Render](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42771/2843) button.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HSjkBdw.png
It is selected. I also tried selecting the alternate start/end frame button which didn't make it work.

As for Samoth's suggestion I believe this is what I was already doing but I used the render button in the properties section instead. This seems to have the same icon as in the preview, so I don't think it would be different.