# Blender rendering deleted video

Tags: rendering, video

I have a project I am working on that involves a view screen I made. At one point, just to tinker with it, I was trying to get a video rendered on that view screen.
All that ended up happening was Blender rendered only that video and not the whole project. I set it up with the movie clip editor section. I decided it wasn't going to work for what I wanted to do anyway so I deleted that video and just put an image on the view screen. I am trying to get Blender to render the project again but it still is only rendering images from the deleted video. I deleted the video from the movie clip editor but it is still being rendered.
Its got to be a simple setting I am overlooking, or at least I hope so. How do I get Blender to go back to rendering the whole project I am working on? If more info is needed, please just ask and I will provide whatever is needed.

Comment: So you're trying to map an image on a TV screen in your 3D scene?

Comment: That too but that renders fine while in the working render mode. Its the full render (F12) that switches to the deleted video. What I want to do is get blender to go back to rendering the scene rather then a video I dont want.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5285/599

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the file after making your changes?

Try reloading the recently saved file.
File >> Revert

This fixes issues like this for me most of the time.

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. Blender just wont stop rendering the image that is the first frame of the video I had in it at one time. Even deleted and not in the folder it wont stop rendering that image. I want Blender to go back to rendering the scene but its rendering a deleted video image.

Comment: @csandhmech How about removing all video data from your .blend? Do you think you could do that? Can you make a lite version to post for us to look at?

Comment: I figured it out just now actually. I had used the movie clip editor to edit the original video that was in the project (that I later deleted) and had taken the video out of that section. I also removed it from the video sequence editor and thought that should of fixed it. What I did not realize was that for some reason, the same video was in the video sequence editor twice. I just saw that and removed the second video and now it renders the scene again. Not sure why it was in twice but whatever, its fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved! If this happens to you, be sure to double check the video sequence editor section! My video ended up there twice for whatever reason. Once I deleted both videos, it rendered the scene once again.

Comment: You should mark your question as "answered".