# Deleted objects showing up in render

Tags: rendering, objects

I moved a minimal background I had to another layer, then decided to just delete it and remake it on that layer, better than before. I made a nice background, and then I went to test it out, and moved it back to render it, and it showed the same everything I had last time! Nothing I had deleted or added was changed! I added and deleted a few things to test it out, and the render stayed the same, no matter where I moved the camera, or moved on the timeline.

I have no idea what to do! I saw a bunch of people say "Maybe you used <kbd>H</kbd> to hide it instead of deleting it."
I tried the solution and it didn't work. I've been using <kbd>X</kbd> to delete everything.

Comment: maybe related?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering

Comment: Yes, that was it! 
Thank you! I read through the intro thing, but I don't know if I need to have a better reputation to say you answered my question, or how to up your post.... My other post was already edited, so I realize there is supposed to be little causal talk about anything, so I'll stop after this. I'll figure it out eventually.