# Why is my blender file now not rendering the current frame

Tags: rendering, image

My file

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38528

keeps rendering the old image, not the changes I've made. A similar questions was answered at

[Came back to a blender file, now not rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering?newreg=eadd53dd93dd43d397bc9fb45fbf0f3b) ,

but I can't find where the problem lies.

Comment: Did you change a texture by painting? If that is the change, then I know the answer.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, it renders fine on my machine... http://i.stack.imgur.com/T5YdZ.gif

Comment: 1. I didn't on purpose, but I may have hit a hot key by accident. 

2. was the head rendered as narrow? It's supposed to be wider.

Comment: This is the wrong render, the face should be much wider http://www.pasteall.org/pic/94129

Comment: I'm running mint. Here, take a look at the wide skull. http://www.pasteall.org/pic/94130

Answer (score 1):

*old question, I guess you figured out meanwhile, but here is the answer*

You have a shapekey Shin that you must set to 0 :

in edit mode it will show you only the active key that you are editing, as soon as you leave Editmode, the final model taking in account the overall shapekeys mix will be displayed (and rendered in your case)

[image]