# Blender Cyles render not rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have made an animation that does not render properly, it will start to render the first couple of tiles and then just stop completely, not progressing any further. I have visited this other question: [Came back to a blender file, now not rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering), and tried that solution but to no avail. My issue is practically identical to that question though.

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwc5svs--7yVeXpYWkF2Ry12Q1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: also just figured I'd specify; the fluid is off because it isn't baked, don't worry about that the only issue is the rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to render your scene and I have no issues. I noticed "Square sample" was checked so you had to much sample to render. Try to render with "Square sample" unchecked (Properties panel -> render -> sampling).

And just for advise, if you are rendering with the CPU, set the tiles to 16*16 instead of 64*64 it sould be a little bit quicker