# Object location problem

Tags: objects

I have a location problem with blender, and it seems blender really doesn't like my object.

To start from the beginning, while I was learning blender, I made a transformer model that was supposed to transform. I cheated and made a robot model and a transformed model and replaced the two whenever they transformed. Thus, my model included the transformed model positioned right in front of the camera with the robot model out of view so I could animate with it when it transformed. This was over this summer.

Recently, I edited the object so it looked better and made the materials more accurate. (I couldn't do this before because the computer I was using was slow and crashed frequently) The reflective materials became more reflective, the transparent materials became more transparent, etc. etc.

However, when I try to move my transformed model (remember the transformed model is right in front of the camera, so I move it to see the robot model) and then render, the render only shows:

a) the old materials

b) the old position of the camera and the transformed model.

When I exit the render, everything is exactly as it was. The only way I can get the render to work is to make the transformed model invisible to the camera, and even then I can't move the camera (in any view). 
Also, to note, blender shows it is loading something, but the load bar isn't moving and I don't know what it is loading.

Comment: Pictures, .blend file? More information would be helpful here.

Comment: `.blend` files can be hosted on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: do you have any strips in the vse? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering

Comment: I will provide a picture. I don't actually know what vse is, so I probably don't have what you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I had some keyframes in animation. I don't know why, but somehow It was not allowing the movement of the object after the rendering stage. Perhaps it was constantly overriding the position of the object even when carrying it out in the modelling.

By the way, I learned blender in a camp called byte camp, and this is why I have a custom UI for blender. I did not make it.

Comment: Instead of writing "THIS QUESTION IS SOLVED" you can simply mark your answer as accepted. Please read: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)