# Black image while rendering

Tags: rendering

While rendering i can see normal image, but in the end it transforms in black image.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/48jaltka0kbxp4z/donut.blend
p.s. i can't put rendered image on the background of the node editor.
 [image: i have checked already similar questions, but it didn't help]

Comment: Possibly related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering. If not VSE then check compositing nodes in Node editor

Comment: Usually happens when the Composite node is disconnected in the compositor - the brief image rendering before black is the render layer node running through the render, but the disconnect returns nothing so the black screen occurs at the end.

Comment: @CraigDJones tnx. The problem was ridiculous, 4 some reason I had 3 couples of Render layer and composit (one behind other), but only 1 couple was connected and I didn't see it.