# Render shows a different frame as the Viewport (Frame-Number is the same)

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view, camera

Hello dear Blenderheads,
I have a problem :)

I testet some animation stuff and when i render a frame, Blender renders some different frame instead of what i see in the viewport. But the frame-number ist the same in viewport and rendered frame (in ImageEditor). Does someone has a hint for me? There is only one camera.

Hope you can help, thanks :)

[image]

Comment: do you have a strip in the VSE?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering

Comment: only an mp3 audio file. can it interfere? ps. it's already disabled

Comment: Maybe there's animation for the objects in the scene created and you moved them without saving new position into key frame?

Comment: unfortunately no. the only object that is moving is the camera, the rest only changes material property, as wanted.

Comment: When I've stuck this sort of thing I clear out Blender's Temporary folder and importantly, any cache files/folders it has inserted into the project's folder.  That often clears out the gremlins.

Comment: @Edgel3D  Never thought of that. I deleted all files in the temp folder (\\user\me\AppData\temp\) which path i looked up in "user preferences". Are there other files/folders that i missed? Still no change.

Comment: Daniel M   Another might be "Render Cache", and perhaps the "Textures" folder.

Comment: @Edgel3D how do i delet those?

Comment: Just had a look in my Blender folders, and apart from that ..\temp one you mentioned, I can't see any that might hold cache files etc  When the inexplicable is happening, I tend to question the codec of the video in the VSE, render or convert it in another application to e.g. avi, see if the same trouble occurs in Blender with that.  I've had problems with some mp4 videos and that's how I overcame those.  Nodes in the compositor can affect things also.  Untick it's box in Render Properties  at right-->Post Processing tab.

Comment: added to the above - could you be rendering from a camera or the scene (3D) window?  You appear to be seeing something entirely different to what's in the VSE.

Comment: I only render the camera (there is only 1 camera in the scene) and i have only this one scene. In the VSE there is only an mp3 to sync the motion with the sound and it (VSE) is deactivated for postprocessing.