# When I Render, it renders a still image of one of my textures and not the camera view and animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, texturing, camera

[Here is my Blend File](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48714)

I've made a scene with a small tv that plays a video.

But when I click render, blender decides to render the texture on the tv only, and not the animation I set up.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VYXN.jpg

somewhere there must be an improper setting that isn't letting me render the camera view but I've searched and can't find it.

Anybody got an answer?

Comment: Can you attach the blend file?

Comment: Cant tell what might be wrong from your image, could you upload the .blend file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I see you have animation on your camera, maybe your camera is so close to the tv screen at that frame thats all that renders just guessing

Comment: Did you setup strips in Video Sequence editor? see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering. Or did you set up compositing nodes which might rewrite the result? Make sure that camera you preview animation from is the camera used in render (active)

Comment: okay I attached the Blend file.

Answer (score 1):

You have your composite node set up to apply your movie over top of the entire render.  Just uncheck **Compositing** under **Post Processing**

[image]