# Shows a cached image when I try to render

Tags: rendering, cache

I'm trying to render and all I get is the same cached image, whether I choose Cycles or Blender Render. I can hide and move objects, but the cached image is all I get when I press the render button. If I remove the images in the output folder, I just get a blank render screen and no rendering happens at all. What do you think is going on here?

Comment: "*What do you think is going on here?*" Is this a riddle? Try posting some actual info about your file so we can diagnose the problem rather than blindly guessing

Comment: Since we are guessing... here's my guess: [A strip, with an older render, in the VSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering)

Comment: Good guess! That's the answer and I would mark it as such. Also, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cegaton's link held the answer:

[Came back to a blender file, now not rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering)

> The Compositor and Sequence settings are enabled by default, so if there is any data in the compositor or the sequencer blender will
>   render from that instead of the scene.
>
> Disable Sequence in Render Settings > Post processing or remove the
>   sequencer strips and it will render the scene instead.