# Blender is rendering another project, and sequencer/compositing is un-checked under Post Processing. Why?

Tags: rendering, animation

when I go to Properties editor > Render > and click "Animate", it's rendering another scene... from a separate .blend file... that isn't open. I tried closing all instances of Blender, I tried searching online (most resulting in references to the "[Blender is rendering an older version my project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/blender-is-rendering-an-older-version-my-project)" thread on this site) and I tried playing around with the settings. There is nothing that I can see in the Video Sequence Editor. I have un-checked Compositing & Sequencer under Properties editor > Post Processing. I have tinkered around with settings and I just have no clue what's causing this issue. I'm still very new to Blender so this is something obvious, please forgive me.

Here is a link to the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wIZ96s0juEdrQXfOimYC1dTM_Jmg8VE3/view?usp=sharing.

[image: Blender Rendering Wrong Project Image]

If you're curious, here is a comparison of what the scene should look like, and the scene from the other file that it's rendering (for some reason). Note that when I click "Render" it renders individual frames fine. It's just when I click "Animation" that it does this:

[image]

Comment: The result in the screenshot is a render of frame 0 of your current file, where the animation starts. Is this what you intended the start frame of the animation to be?

Comment: @JtheNinja frames 0-99 to give smoke some time to spread. I plan to import the exported frames into After Effects. Those first 99 frames will probably end up as cut B-roll, but I was going to render them out anyway. In the picture, the render is from an entirely different project though, hence my bewilderment.

Comment: The partial render in your screenshot looks like the scene in your .blend to me. Could you explain what about it looks wrong/how it should look instead?

Comment: @gandalf3, I added an example to my original post showing what it should look like, and an example of the file that it's actually rendering (you can see that the geometry in the scene is completely different).

Comment: Oh my... I figured it out. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot I keyframed the Focal Length from very small to big for a zooming in effect in each file, making them look similar. I’ll escort myself out now... 
[image]