# Blender does not update the file's information when rendering

Tags: rendering

I render to file sequences then i re-render the same scene to same folder using exactly same name. So i'm replacing the old render. When i check the render files in explorer (windows 10) the data information is not updating. It's still showing the date of couple days ago (when i did the previous render). This is really confusing when i need to check in explorer which frames has been updated /replaced with new render.

Is this Blender problem ? or windows 10?

Comment: Are there any strips in the VSE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [blender is rendering older versions of my project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5285/1853)

Comment: Have you check the Overwrite box? Maybe it is skipping existing files with the same name.

Comment: @rob Not skipping at all, i check and re-load the render into compositing app (like Nuke etc). Everytime i rendered , the output is updating. so it's 1000% confirmed that the render files has been replaced  but the date is still showing the old one (in window explorer). For example i render the red sphere 2 days ago, then now i change the color to green. If i load the render, it's showing the green sphere but still the date is showing 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate that in Windows 10 and the default Explorer window. By creating a basic animation with the default Cube in Green and then re-rendering with Red.

If I check the resulting file *Properties* then, the **Date Modified** and **Date Accessed** values are updated correctly.

This is expected behaviour. Windows is only showing the **Created Date**

In Explorer you can go to the **View** menu and click **Add Columns** to add **Date Modified** and "**Choose Columns**" to add **Date Accessed**.

From what I can tell, this is when Windows decides the folder you are in is designated"**Photos**", as all my other folders default to show **Date Modified**.

*/me shakes fist at Microsoft*

Comment: Thanks a lot. This stupid windows things is annoying.