# how to render the correct animation

Tags: animation

My animation keeps rendering the video editor place not the animation area.  If someone could help me that would be great.

Comment: This is a very common problem with an easy solution. You need to untick "sequencer" as is seen in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5286 Change this setting if you want to change between rendering the animation and rendering your Video sequence. Happy Blending! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender is rendering an older version my project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/blender-is-rendering-an-older-version-my-project)