# render engine will not change from workbench

Tags: animation

I am doing an animation project and i used workbench to quickly render out the animation (i rendered to PNG sequence). However when i try to final render still images for testing all i get is the workbench version of the render. I've tried cycles and Eevee with no luck.

When i set viewport from shaded to rendered using Cycles or Eevee i get proper rendered viewport as normal.

Old files work as expected as well so i don't think blender is broken :). so its something i did when using workbench?

If i copy and paste all geometry lights and camera to a new empty scene. all is well. Its so weird.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Tony

Comment: Version 2.83 i'm guessing?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/blender-is-rendering-an-older-version-my-project

Comment: OH YES!!!! thank you! Makes perfect sense that it works when copying and pasting to a clean blend file. and yes i'm on 2.3 version