# Why is blender rendering a different file from my current one?

Tags: rendering

When I go to render, for some reason Blender opens a finished render from another file. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/blender-is-rendering-an-older-version-my-project

Comment: Yes thank you very much.