# Blender only render one frame of animation

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, cloth-simulation

I have a 300 frame Eevee animation, but when rendering I only get multiples of the same frame. I have looked at similar posts on Stack Exchange, but they don't solve my problem.

Animation works perfectly in viewport. I render using Ctrl + F12. Cloth physics is baked for the animated object.

Blend file: https://we.tl/t-yFyttsa6aH

Render settings:
[image]

Frame that get rendered:
[image]

Comment: I opened your file and I get empty render also for a static render.

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/blender-is-rendering-an-older-version-my-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deselected these two options and I can render the correct animation:

[image]