# Video file is much shorter than the number of frames set for the output

Tags: rendering

When I render animation, it renders all 3000 frames (avi jpg) but, the resulting video file is much shorter than the 3000 frame render. I believe that it is only creating a video file that is  about the first 1200 frames (it is stopping at a point that I had a previous render going to) event though I am rendering 3000 frames.

Why in the world would it render all of the frames in the timeline but only provide a video with less than half of the rendered frames?

[image]

Comment: Please make the title for your questions more specific and not a vague or general one.

Comment: Do you have any strips in the sequencer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/blender-is-rendering-an-older-version-my-project

Comment: I unchecked sequencer in the post processing section and still have the same result.

Comment: might sound stupid to ask but, did you run out of space on the hard drive?

Comment: No, I have over 1.5 tb left. I got it to work with an ffmpeg video rather than avi jpeg but, it still  was more of a work around than a solution.