# F12 Does Not Render New Image

Tags: rendering, image, error

F12 does not work correctly. When I press the button, Blender shows me the last render (maybe older) result every time. I removed and add again the camera and there is no another camera. I rebooted the computer, downgraded to 2.82 from 2.9 but I cannot view any new result when I press F12. How can I fix that? If u necessary I can upload .blend file anywhere.

Comment: Do you have any strips on the VSE? If so disable the sequencer for output. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/blender-is-rendering-an-older-version-my-project

Comment: Thanks a lot. I deleted it and saw your answer before the new result. :)

Comment: Yes. It's worked for me.